# How to configure MacTex and texstudio?

Tags: pdftex, miktex, compiling, texstudio, mactex

Earlier I was using texstudio with MikTex. In MikTex, I am facing some issue with its updates. So, I downloaded MacTex. How to configure texstudio with MacTex? When I am running texstudio, it is taking MikTex compiler. The error is shown below.

Sorry, but /usr/local/bin/pdflatex did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: /Users/bp/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/data/miktex/log/pdflatex.log

pdflatex: major issue: So far, you have not checked for MiKTeX updates.

Comment: Can you uninstall MikTeX?

Comment: Facing problem with MikTex. It is neither taking updates nor getting uninstalled.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling texstudio? I think by default texstudio for Mac is setup for MacTeX which places its binaries in a special folder (plus some shortcuts) to make it easy for editors. You probably had to edit the path settings in texstudio to get miktex to work on the Mac.

Comment: MikTek I had installed first, then now I am trying with MacTex.